# Recurring sections in Web Forms For Marketers, Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I am playing around with the web forms for marketers plugin for Sitecore 8.1, and I need to build recurring sections.

Recurring section is in the meaning that a little button will occur at the side of a section of input fields. When it is pressed the input fields are replicated below.

I am not sure how to implement this. I have looked into creating a new custom complex field type, but haven't found any good documentation that elaborated on how to build these kinds of sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web forms for marketers plugin is not suited for data without a schema. All fields generated in JavaScript on the client ill simply be discarded.

Ultimately the solution is the make a fixed number of sections, and then make some hide/show magic in JavaScript.

This solution does not allow the user to create unbound number of recurrences. But it solves the basic problem-